# Python List comprehension, lookup table

Tags: python

I've started using/learning list-comprehensions, as an exercise I decided to use the following code:

```
def data_idx(data):
    if data <= 15:
        n = ''
    elif data <= 31:
        n = 2
    elif data <= 47: 
        n = 3
    elif data <= 63: 
        n = 4
    else:  
        n = 5
    return n
```

I'm wondering, if it is possible to simplify the above code to one line?

I've tried the following approach:

```
data = 63 
limits = [31, 47, 63, 100]
if data > 15:
    x = [n+2 for n in range(len(limits)) if limits[n] <= data < limits[n+1]][0]
else:
    x = ''
```

But I don't know how to deal with values `<= 15`, to make an output `''`.

Comment: your code is not equivalent teach other.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html should be helpful

Comment: @Djib2011, hmmm... I wonder why this line of code works in python3.7... 


x = [n+2 for n in range(len(limits)) if limits[n] <= data < limits[n+1]][0]

Comment: @Djib2011 `A < B < C` is permitted in Python.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'll delete my comment

Comment: List comprehensions shouldn't be used for side effects. As I see it, that's a side-effect: you are creating the list just to take the first element. To be honest, you shouldn't change your code. It is clear, readable and efficient enough. Anything else will just make the reader of your code scratch their forehead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in Python, the simplification of a `if/elif/else` structure is done by using a dict. For example:

```py
if n == 2:
    x = 'two'
elif n == 3:
    x = 'three'
else:
    x = 'na'
```

Can be simplified into:

```
x = {2: 'two', 3: 'three'}.get(n, 'na')
```

But since you're comparing and not checking equality, this gets trickier. You are also not using fixed ranges so can't use [a switch-like dict with ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884270/how-to-create-a-switch-case-in-python-with-the-cases-being-intervals).

Still, to emulate your `if`s structure, you can create a matching of `limits` and their relevant symbol and find the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) one that matches using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (rather than a list-comprehension):

```py
def data_idx(data):
    limits  = [15, 31, 47, 63]
    symbols = ['',  2,  3,  4]

    return next((symbol for limit, symbol in zip(limits, symbols) if data <= limit), 5)
```

This simply checks in what range the data falls into and returns the matching symbol. If none matched (so `data` is greater than `63`), it will return `5` (the *default* for [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't recommend you use this for anything that you or someone else will have to read in the future. There are better, clearer solutions that don't use list comprehension to accomplish this.

But you asked for a one-liner using list comprehension...

```
data = 63
limits = [0, 15, 31, 47, 63]

n = [idx if idx > 1 else '' for idx, limit in enumerate(limits, 1) if data > limit][-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def data_idx(data):
    return [repr('') if i <= 15 else 2 if i <= 31 else 3 if i <= 47 else 4 if i <= 63 else 5 for i in (data, )][0]

limits = [15, 31, 47, 63, 100]

for i in limits:
    print(data_idx(i))
```

```
''
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Why do you even use list-comp here? You can just replace `i` with `data` and return the expression of the list-comp... No reason to create a list with element and take the first element - just return that element...